# Meaning of 甜-Z (Z is the upper-case English letter)

Tags: translation, meaning

This is apparently a jargon engineering term for something to do with frequency (Hz).

I'm guessing it might be something to do with resonance ("sweet spot"?) but I've not run into it, and neither have the two native Mandarin-speaking engineers I've asked.

Comment: What's the context? It might be just a typo.

Comment: It is likely that it is the result of wrong OCR. I have seen 甜z as OCR of 5Hz before (http://www.google.com/patents/CN103848774B?cl=zh).

Comment: It could also be a partial entry from a Pinyin-based input method: tianzhen 天真 truncated might produce 甜z. Context would help…

Comment: @zhantongz is correct- I found the actual original Chinese in CN104237564A and it was 5Hz, just as you said! The so-called original was OCR'd and had the 'sweet' character, which is what fooled me. If you put this as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

甜Z is likely the result of imperfect OCR (optical character recognition) for "5Hz". The machine probably sees "**5H**" as "**甜**".

It's usually seen in Google's OCR for Chinese patents. If you need to search for original patent text for clarification, you can go to  http://epub.sipo.gov.cn/gjcx.jsp and search the title.

Answer (score 1):

Thank Stan for pointing out my digression.

I see the patent page. I think it is just a wrong identification of OCR. Please see the [0036] in APPLICATION page, it is the 5.5 Hz in that position.

-------former answer--not fit this question-----------------------
Do you mean that?

[image: 甜 - zig]

This is a abbreviation.

That has the same meaning with 甜甜. But it is not a formal style. For example,  When you write  a draft, you can use it but you can not use it in some official documents.

Comment: Welcome to Chinese.SE! Whilst, reading others' answers and comments before answering a question is a good habit - it saves your time from digression.

Comment: @Stan Thank you, I will notice that when I see next question.^_^

Comment: As the image above, it true that the mark means duplication of the single character ahead. It is widely used by senior Chinese born in 1950s-1970s, but not very popular now.

Comment: But still very popular in Japan.